# How to implement different working on same function through inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, typeahead

HTML:

```
<input type="textbox" class="typeahead" id="location" onkeyup="localTypeahead('location')">
<input type="textbox" class="typeahead" id="location2" onkeyup="localTypeahead('location2')">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function localTypeahead(divid){  

     var citylocalvalues = [{'id':101,'name':'jaipur'}, {'id':102,'name':'delhi'}];

     jQuery('input.typeahead').typeahead({   
        onSelect: function(item) {
        jQuery("#"+divid).val(item.value);    
     },  
     source: citylocalvalues   
     });
}
```

Above examples functionality seems that two different working will be happened, and on each textbox the value will be set respectively.
But what I'm receiving the value change to first textbox only in both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, setting `onclick`s in HTML (inline JS) is not a good idea. You would ideally want your functionality separated from your viewing elements. So what I suggest is you remove `onkeyup="function(...)"`, and set either in your JS file or in a js script at the bottom of your html document as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#location').on('keyup', function(ev) {
    // You can access the object that fired the keyup event through the variable ev here
  });
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('input.typeahead')` should match the correct input (the specific input you're currently typeaheading), change it to : `jQuery('#' + divid)`